# sys.getsizeof() return different sizes values on different machines and same python version

Tags: python

**sys.getsizeof()** returns different sizes. For example in Machine 1 
`sys.getsizeof('h')` returns `22`, but in machine 2 it returns `38`.

Why machine 2 is `+16`?

Machine 1 :

`Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2`

`lsb_release -r
Release: 16.04`

`uname -a 
Linux linux1 4.4.0-96-generic #119-Ubuntu SMP Tue Sep 12 14:58:51 UTC 2017 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux`

Same python, same gcc. Machine 2 is the same as machine 1 except the kernel version, it is different:

`Linux linux2 4.4.0-62-generic #83-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 18 14:10:15 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Question is similiar to this: [python sys.getsizeof method returning different sizes on different versions of python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36152435/python-sys-getsizeof-method-returning-different-sizes-on-different-versions-of-p)

Comment: this is an exact _duplicate_ of the question you linked to. you have 32 bit on one side and 64 bits on the other side, this is covered by the question&answer already.

Comment: Ohhhhh i didnt see the arch . Thanks

Answer (score 1):

getsizeof() returns the memory bytes used to store that variable/object. As your OS-es have different architecture x32 and x64 , they allocate memory differently.
You can find more here:
https://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?p=1007393